# Does a banished Daedra take the loot with it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been avoiding using any weapons that banish "Summoned Daedra up to level XX" back to Oblivion, because I want the fire / frost / void salts they drop.  I have been assuming that when they are banished, they just disappear - is this correct, or do they leave behind the same pile of ashes (with loot) that you get when killing them the regular way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summoned daedra disappear anyway when they die. You can't get fire salts from a summoned fire atronach, only from wild atronachs that leave a corpse.

So banishing summoned creatures does cause them to disappear, but they wouldn't have been able to drop anything anyway, so there's no reason to avoid doing so.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that distinction.  That said, I'll stick with other enchantments on my weapons that will affect more creatures than "banish" would.